# How to adjust the image to fit in the window width and height using CSS

Tags: css, html

I am trying to fit the image (dimensions : 1678 x 1302) into window's width and height as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
            }
            #bgimg {
                background-image: url("background2.jpeg");
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg" width=500 height=500>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The image should fit the viewing window. I can't use 'background-repeat: repeat-y' as the image shade is different at the bottom of the image when compared to top. Is there any way to fit the image properly (without missing any part of the image) to the viewing window even if image sizes doesn't match with the window sizes?

Comment: `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
            }
            #bgimg {
                background-image:  url(images/marc.jpg);
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg" width=500 height=500>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Friday. I felt image is getting cut. Width wide image is getting covered. But height wide, while image is not getting displayed. I am not sure how to attach the image file and output here to show the difference.